# What is different among this.ActiveControl = XControl , XControl.Focus() in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I work on a C# Winform project.

I don't know what is different among

1. `this.ActiveControl = XControl;`
2. `XControl.Focus();`

Sometimes `XControl.Focus()` do not work and I have to set `this.ActiveControl = XControl`. I don't know why it happens. I'm confused, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus.aspx) is rather clear about this:

> Focus is a low-level method intended primarily for custom control authors. Instead, application programmers should use the [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.select.aspx) method or the [ActiveControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.activecontrol.aspx) property for child controls, or the [Activate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activate.aspx) method for forms.

So it sounds like you should be setting the `ActiveControl` property. It is probably doing something extra that `Focus` does not do.

You could look in the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) to find out exactly what, but that seems like a waste of time to me. It is always better to follow the documented behavior, rather than relying on implementation details.

Armed only with the information in the documentation and what I know about Windows programming, I can make a pretty good guess that the `Focus` method simply calls the Win32 [`SetFocus` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646312.aspx), whereas the `ActiveControl` property probably has a bunch of additional logic to handle cases where calling `SetFocus` directly will not work.

For example, the linked documentation for `SetFocus` is very explicit about the fact that the window to which you are setting focus must be attached to the calling thread's message queue. The `ActiveControl` property might work around that. Or, it might have code that handles nested controls.